# How to implement a Mysql client like REPL in Python

Tags: python, nonblocking, fabric

I want a client with [Fabric](https://github.com/fabric/fabric) and Python [raw_input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) builtin function to implement a Mysql Client like console.

Every ok for single instruction. But for multiline SQLs, fab process a SQL need some times (ssh to remote server and echo the SQL to local `mysql` client), and then raw_input will lose the reset of multiline SQLs. In the `mysql` console you could paste multiline SQLs and will been executed perfect every single instruction.

Why not using `mysql` client directly ? There are a gate of the servers. And we need a simple alias to avoid write the parameters every time. And some post jobs after execute SQLs (post the echo of the execution, etc.)

I guess the fabric `run` was blocking the `sys.stdin` and make the input losing. But I'm failing execute `run` in a independent thread.

Comment: Why do you care about entering parameters to `mysql`, when you are using `Fabric`, which does it for you? Anyway, if you want to build a REPL, you shall search for command line parsers like `argparse`, `nose`, my favourite `docopt` or others.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky My means using mysql client directly without fabric. Yes, I need a REPL, but fabric is handling the parameters of application good enough for me. So I didn't care the command line parsers.

Comment: I like Fabric, using it myself, great for remote machine management and provides usable command line interface. However, you ask for a bit more advanced application, which does not fit Fabric style so well. That is why I would go for other parser. Trying that with Fabric would be difficult, with other it will be rather easy (but be prepared for some amount of coding ans the Mysql interface offers many choices).

Comment: @JanVlcinsky Thanks, that's make sense. I'm also trying to find other way to do this.